# Indesigne paragraph styling error

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

So I've been working on some project of mine and long story short, I have to correct paragraph stylings and so on, because it didn't exprot correctly. Now I've been doing this for over a 1100 paragraphs and it was as it should be until the paragraph 1142 which when I apply style deletes everything that is after it, for no apperant reason. This only happens with this paragraphs, all the others befor it and after it apply styles correctly. I really dont get this. Thanks ! (since I dont have 10 reputation ill link the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K7ec.gif)

Comment: I had the same problem a few times. This is style related, e.g. try to apply a different style and the text will be there. It does not disappear completely, if you add lots of page with linked frames it will appear eventually. Make sure the space after the number is a legit character and try to tweak the style, keep options, maybe?

Comment: This question is not about programming as stated in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and can better be asked on [graphicdesign.se].

Answer (score 0):

Not a programming problem; it's [PICNIC](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/PICNIC).

Looking closely at the image, I see the newly applied style does not allow hyphenation. The single word in that paragraph is too long, and since you do not allow word breaks, InDesign tries to move it to a next frame, hoping that will be wide enough. (Apparently it is not.)

Enable hyphenation, or break the word in two with a space, or make the column wider, or use a smaller font. With your style parameters it simply does not fit.